# Odd behaviour with ::selection and WebKit

Tags: css, webkit, selection, textselection

On my website, I declare the `::selection` pseudo-element with a background, text-colour, and text shadow. But when you highlight the whole site, you'll see the accurate selection except for a few spots where you'll still see the system `selection`. I was able to figure out why those spots are acting strange. If you have an inline element and a block element afterwards, the space between the inline and block element will remain with the system default selection. I don't understand why. Is this a bug? On most websites I've been to (with the selection element declared), I see these *spots*, it's quite an oversight. Can somebody tell me if its a bug or normal? And possibly explain why it is behaving like that.

I put together a ["jsFiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/f7j58/).

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 19. What browser are you using?

Comment: @animuson Safari (latest) OS X, last time I checked Chrome was on another's computer, didn't know the version but saw the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a "bug" considering that it's not a standard feature. The W3C has no defined standards for how it should behave, as it was removed from the CSS3 specifications early on.

From the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3aselection):

> its behavior was under-specified, especially with nested elements

Bottom line: there's no specification that says what's *supposed* to happen with nested elements. So, technically, it's not an incorrect rendering, even though it doesn't make much sense. Ultimately, it's still an "experimental" feature. You can try filing a bug report with Safari.